# Count total size of records before paging and return them after paging without hitting the database twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a Paging method where it takes the page and limits then applies them to the set that was given (a pre-filter/queries might be applied to) then  it applies the pagination to it so nothing has to be done in the server side from counting the records to applying the pagination (only counts the final result, which is stored in memory anyway)

```cs
        public async Task<PagingServiceResponse<T>> Apply<T>(IQueryable<T> set)
        {
            var httpQuery = _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Query;
            var pageValue = httpQuery.LastOrDefault(x => x.Key == "page").Value;
            if (pageValue.Count > 0) int.TryParse(pageValue, out _page);
            var limitValue = httpQuery.LastOrDefault(x => x.Key == "limit").Value;
            if (limitValue.Count > 0) int.TryParse(limitValue, out _limit);
            if (_limit > 1000 || _limit <= 0) _limit = 1000;
            if (_page <= 0) _page = 1;
            _size = await set.CountAsync();
            set = set.Take(_limit);
            if (_page > 1) set = set.Skip(_page * _limit);

            var data = await set.ToListAsync();
            var currentSize = data.Count;
            return new PagingServiceResponse<T>
            {
                Data = data,
                Size = _size,
                CurrentSize = currentSize,
                Page = _page,
                PerPage = _limit
            };
        }
```

So the problem here is that this hits the database twice, to check the total count (`CountAsync`) and receive the data (`ToListAsync`)

and I'm trying to not do that since it performs the query twice, which is not pure query, there are filter operations that are applied to it.

If there is any advice for another approach or something I am all ears.

I'm using PostgreSQL & entity framework core(npgsql)

Comment: Just don't report the total number of rows.  In the UI say "Page 1 of ?" or somesuch.

Comment: Two queries are required if you're using pagination (not retrieving all the records) as you need the count query.  You could cache the count for a few minutes to enhance performance and provide an estimation of pages rather than real-time.

Comment: @Devon can you further explain how I can apply the caching approach?

Answer (score 2):

No, the whole premise of pagination is that you need to know the complete row count before obtaining a sub-set of total records. The only way that can be done in 1 query hit is to load *all* records. (Which is a way worse option for large sets! :)

One issue I see is that you are using `Take` to take a limit of rows (0<=1000?) then skipping the page size and page #? To me if the limit is 1000 and your page size is 25, and you're loading the first page, wouldn't this return 1000 rows? (rather than the first page's 25?)  Normally I'd expect a paging query to act more like:

```
var pagedData = set.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Where `page` is 0-based. (0 = page #1).  This ensures that only a max of 25 rows are pulled back.

Some things you can do to further mitigate the cost of pagination queries and obtaining a count:

1. Structure your query build & execution so that Ordering and Projections (`Select`/`ProjectTo`) occur after obtaining the `Count`.
2. Make sure the context is short-lived and "fresh". This won't speed up the Count, but loading the sub-set will be slower the more entities that are being tracked.
3. When an accurate count is not needed, provide a rough one that can be expanded as users select a further page, or can opt for retrieving a complete count.

Getting a rough count is similar to how a Google search gives an approximation, not a real count of results. The relatively simple technique I use is to take the current page size and # of pages displayed by the pager. The pagination control needs to be tweaked to not display navigation to "Last" page, and displaying a record count needs to be adjusted as well.

So for example 10 pages with a page size of 25. Before getting a count I base the count on the top ({PageSize} x {MaxPageCount} + 1) or 251. To get `maxPageCount` we need to look at 
the page number against the # of expected pages to display. (I.e. 10)

```
int maxPageCount = (((page) / 10)+1) * 10;
int roughCountLimit = pageSize * maxPageCount + 1;

rowCount = set.Take(roughCountLimit).Count();
bool isRoughCount = rowCount == roughCountLimit;
var pagedData = set.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

For pages 1 to 10 This will return up to 11 pages. 
I.e.

```
page #1 (0) / 10 = 0.  (0+1)* 10 = 10.
page #2 (1) / 10 = 0.  (0+1)* 10 = 10.
page #10 (9) / 10 = 0. (0+1)* 10 = 10.
```

The idea is that the pager will show something like:

"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ..." while our page count would be set up to look at `isRoughCount` and display:  "250+" rather than "251" if `isRoughCount` is `True`.

If and when a user selects "..." to load page #11 then going back to the `maxPageCount`:

```
 page #11 (10) / 10 = 1. (1+1)* 10 = 20.
```

This will result in `roughCountLimit` becoming 501. This will load up to 21 pages of records.  If the database happened to only return 251 records, then Page 11 would still display with the 1 remaining record, and since isRoughCount would be false, the row count will update to display "251". Otherwise, the page count will be updated to display "500+" If the user continues to navigate through pages using the "...", the rough count limit will continue to increase. This will make the query gradually slower, but for those initial few sets of pages, the query will retrieve counts significantly faster.

The key thing about pagination and searching is that users should have the tools to find the data typically on the first page, or maybe first handful of pages of results. The actual # of times they would need to navigate through 10 pages of results, let alone more than 10 pages of results should be nearly never. (This would be an indication that you need better searching/filtering capabilities) At the same time, even with really good searching, dealing with really large data sets, a user generally won't care if there is 5000 rows or 500,000,000 rows. We can greatly speed up querying by reporting that there are "at least" 250 rows, then expand on that if and only if it is needed. The page count can be displayed as a hyperlink to run a specific full count query if they may need, or are simply curious about the specific 504,231,188 row count. That (expensive) fact doesn't need to be part of every query.

Comment: very good answer, and thanks for pointing the issue out I was not aware I re-arranged the order (skip -> take), but it's true that in searching the user does not care about the number of rows but in this particular case he does because of the nature of the data that is returned (examination in this case) but I can do that same thing with {x}+ rows

Comment: "the whole premise of pagination is that you need to know the complete row count before obtaining a sub-set of total records" - I'm not sure that's true. The primary benefit of server-side pagination is that you only load a small number of records at once. You _can_ do this without the total row count; you just can't tell the user how many results/pages there are, so you give up the specific page navigation buttons. But those niceties are secondary - you can still navigate through the pages with next/previous buttons and you still benefit from not loading the whole result set into memory.

Comment: Correct, the solution I provided was a compromise that can give you useful alternative to provide numbered page results with a reduced cost to get the record count. Like the saying goes, "The best place to hide a dead body is page 2 of Google" which I'd say is more like "page 4 of search results". Users like to have quick navigation links for stuff that might be sorted by name etc. rather than just Next/Prev. For those that want an actual row count, this can be fetched on demand using a count action off a link in the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hit the database just once to get both number of objects and objects. If you want to do pagination both queries are required. [Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008647/get-the-total-number-of-records-when-doing-pagination)